# X1 not correlated with Y, but when controlling for X2 in a regression it is?

Tags: regression

I'm currently doing my dissertation and have run into a bit of trouble. 
My predictors are positively correlated (and are conceptually extremely similar).

$X_1$ is not correlated with the criterion while $X_2$ is. When $X_1$ is entered into a single predictor regression it has no relationship to $y$. When $X_1$ and $X_2$ are entered into a regression  $X_2$ has the expected positive sign relationship with $y$ (b = .879, P<.001, 5% unique variance) , while $X_1$ strangely has a statistically significant negative sign relationship with $y$ (b= -1.148, P<.001, 9% unique variance).

[image]

Could this be an example of suppression?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an example of Omitted Variable Bias, where the bias is attenuating the significance of $X_1$. The explanation of this in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) is very straightforward, so I will copy its notation.

Basically, the true model is:

$$ y = a + bX_1 + cX_2 + u$$

Assume the relationship between $X_2$ and $X_1$ is:

$$ X_2 = d + fX_1 + e $$

Then, your reduced model is:

$$ y = (a+cd) + (b+cf)X_1 + (u+ce) $$

Thus, what the reduced model estimates is $b+cf$, where $cf$ is the bias of the estimated "true" parameter $b$. The bias emerges because $X_1$ is capturing not only its influence on $y$ ($b$) but also that of $X_2$ ($c$), with a "strength" of $f$ (their partial correlation).

You have not provided the value of $f$, so I cannot compute that bias, but if you do so, you might find that it is "close" to zero. In effect, $f$ should be positive, as it is indicated by their correlation value (0.744), whereas $c$ is also positive and $b$ negative. So $cf$ (positive) is attenuating the "true" value of $b$ (negative). You can compute the standard error of $b+cf$ using the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to check its significance.

PS: actually, I get the impression that 0.744 is the coefficient of regressing $X_2$ on $X_1$ (rather than merely their correlation coefficient). If so, then "roughly" speaking, $b+cf=-1.148+0.879/0.744=0.03$. As you see, very close to the original coefficient, 0.01, and to zero.